# performance of copying directories

Tags: c#, performance, copy

I am using C# to copy files from one directory to another directory.
I am using code from msdn but its pretty slow taking a minute or so to
copy a couple of gigs. It only takes seconds in explorer.
http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/257490-How-Copy-directories-in-C
Surly there a faster way..:)

```
        private static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
    {
        DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
        DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

        CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
    }

    private static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        // Check if the target directory exists, if not, create it.
        if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }

        // Copy each file into it's new directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
        }

        // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
        }
    }
```

---

Using Parallel I was able to copy 6gigs in under a minute faster than explorer and xcopy.

---

```
private static void CopyAll(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
{
    string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    Parallel.ForEach(directories, dirPath =>
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
    }); 

    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    Parallel.ForEach(files, newPath =>
    {
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Explorer probably does a _rename_ of the top level directory, not a copy of each and every file.

Comment: @Oded: this is copying not renaming so files should stay in both directories

Comment: Perhaps explorer does this in multiple threads...

Comment: @Oded that only applies to *moving*, not to *copying*.  When you copy a directory in Explorer, it creates copies of all the files in the directory.

Comment: @sll - If that's indeed the case, then a couple of gigs will not get copied in seconds, even in Explorer.

Comment: @phoog - My thinking is that the OP is not describing a copy but a move.

Comment: @sll probably not, since there's only one disk drive (or, at most, two).  Having multiple threads would be counterproductive, as it would cause excessive seeking.

Comment: @Oded but the sample code clearly uses `FileInfo.CopyTo`.

Comment: @phoog - Yes, but the description of what happens in Explorer sounds to me like a move occurred rather than a copy.

Comment: @Oded just to be certain i just copyed a 6 gig folder in explorer using copy and it only took 60 seconds. so its still taking longer

Comment: 6 gig in 60 seconds is very fast. How much slower is your approach?

Comment: @Oded give me a couple of minutes to test that speed

Comment: @Oded maybe, but I just copied a 1.4 gig file on my computer using explorer, and it took 16 seconds.  So it's plausible that a couple of gigs could be copied in far less than a minute.

Comment: @phoog - The OP is talking about 60 secs for 6Gb (not quite the description in the question), but without something to compare it to, it is difficult to say.

Comment: Have you looked at [`Directory.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx)?

Comment: So are you saying there is no problem???

Comment: @Oded sorry about the confusion i have multiple files with the same name but different that confused me. there is a problem the code takes twice as long as windows explorer it takes 2.1 minutes to copy a file while explorer takes 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What u are using is recursion. It always slows the system.

Use this as it has no recursion.

```
void CopyAll (string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
{
    //Now Create all of the directories
    foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*.*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

    //Copy all the files
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
}
```

Comment: this was closer to explorer performance 6gigs in a minute and a half a little faster than xcopy

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probabbly on *overwriteé of the file.
I see that you call

```
fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
```

where `true` means overwrite the file if it exists.

Based on this I *suppose* so that it's a case in your app to overwrite already existing files.

The stuff should  go faster if you

- first rename destination directory with some temporary unique name
- after just copy source to dest (so no overwrite)

if *success* remove temp directory, if *fails* remove all copied files and rename temp to its original name.

*Should* be faster.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks tigran but the vast amount of the time there isn't a file in the new directory

Comment: @caseyr547: did you ever try to invoke [xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) and see the performance difference ?

Comment: @Tigran - Or robocopy as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect @Oded is correct, and you're comparing a copy to a move.

If you want to ensure that what you're doing is the same as the shell does, you could look into [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx), or (on Vista or newer) [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx). At least as far as I know, you'd have to use `SHFileOperation` via P/Invoke. IFileOperation is a COM interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big problem with using Parallel.ForEach loops with creating directories, the first thing you need to be aware of, are sub directories nested within other directories, if Parallel creates directories out of order, the code can be thrown due to trying to create directory level 8 while directory level 6 was not even made yet.