# How to create a recursive function to copy all files and folders

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, recursion

I am trying to create a function that will recursively copy a source folder and all files and folders inside of it to a different location.

At the moment, I have to define each folder within the main folder, which is making the code bloated and redundant.

What's a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: MSDN has an example: [How to: Copy Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx).

Comment: More efficient than [missing code/details] ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to recursively copy contents in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627504/what-is-the-best-way-to-recursively-copy-contents-in-c)

Answer (score 11):

take a look at my question:

[performance of copying directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014322/performance-of-copying-directories)
i used parallel foreach and it is very fast

```
private static void CopyAll(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
{

string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Parallel.ForEach(directories, dirPath =>
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
}); 

string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Parallel.ForEach(files, newPath =>
{
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Source: [C# - Copy files and folders recursively from source to destination folder in c-sharp](http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.ca/2011/07/c-copy-files-and-folders-recursively.html)

```
public static void CopyFolder(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)  
{  
    if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))  
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder); 

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);  
    foreach (string file in files)  
    {  
        string name = Path.GetFileName(file);  
        string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);  
        File.Copy(file, dest);  
    }  
    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);  
    foreach (string folder in folders)  
    {  
        string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);  
        string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);  
        CopyFolder(folder, dest);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Throws an exception if the destination directory ("dest" on line 17) doesn't exist. Insert this on line 18:
if (!Directory.Exists(dest))
 Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way

```
 void Copy(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
 {
   Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);
   foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
       File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));

   foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
       Copy(directory, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GetDirectories/GetFiles is somewhat out of date in my eyes, I would use `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(source);` instead as it is faster.