# Recursively Transfer And Break Up Files/Folders

Tags: c#

I wrote an app for going through very large fileshares and while it copies them to the new location, another HD in this case, it breaks what's being copied over into folders containing 4,500 or less items(Libraries to be synced to sharepoint online). Compensating for long file paths. Here is a code sample of the functions I have working in tandem that takes in the source and destination then does the copying breaking described above:

Edit:

Alright I found a solution and this method below is working as I want it to, it is really slow as you can imagine looking at how I have it counting the childitems as it's running though so if anyone has a better/faster solution to the problem please feel free to post it. Otherwise, thank you all very much for the help, it's much appreciated. Here's the code I currently have:

```
#region Recursive_Copy
    public static List<string> OutOfReachAreas = new List<string>();
    private static List<FileInfo> Overflow = new List<FileInfo>();
    private static List<string> AccessDeniedList = new List<string>();
    private static bool FirstTime = true;
    private static int LibraryCount { get; set; }
    private static bool ToSwith = false;
    private static int CountLimit = 4250;
    public static void RecursiveCopy(string SourceDir, string DestDir)
    {
        if (!FirstTime)
        {
            LibraryCount =
            ((Directory.GetDirectories((Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + "Library" + Program.LibraryCounter.ToString()), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count())
           + (Directory.GetFiles((Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + "Library" + Program.LibraryCounter.ToString()), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()));
        }

        if (LibraryCount <= CountLimit && !FirstTime)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(SourceDir);
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
                FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
                string CurrentLibrary = "Library" + Program.LibraryCounter.ToString();

                if (!Directory.Exists(DestDir))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DestDir);
                }

                if (Overflow.Count() != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var OverflowInst in Overflow)
                    {
                        string NewestLibrary = Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + "Library" + Program.LibraryCounter + "\\" + OverflowInst.Name;
                        if (!File.Exists(NewestLibrary))
                        {
                            OverflowInst.CopyTo(NewestLibrary, false);
                        }
                    }
                    Overflow.Clear();
                }

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo TestPath = new DirectoryInfo(Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + CurrentLibrary);
                        int TestPathCount = (TestPath.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()) + (TestPath.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count());
                        if (TestPathCount <= CountLimit)
                        {
                            string temppath = Path.Combine(DestDir, file.Name);
                            DirectoryInfo TestTemp = new DirectoryInfo(temppath);
                            if (!TestTemp.Exists && !AccessDeniedList.Contains(file.Name))
                            {
                                file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FileInfo OverflowToAdd = new FileInfo(file.FullName);
                            Overflow.Add(OverflowToAdd);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        AccessDeniedList.Add(file.Name);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var subDir in dirs)
                {
                    DirectoryInfo TestPath = new DirectoryInfo(Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + CurrentLibrary);
                    int TestPathCount = (TestPath.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()) + (TestPath.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count());
                    if (TestPathCount <= CountLimit)
                    {
                        if (ToSwith)
                        {
                            ToSwith = false;
                            string PathToSwitch = Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + "Library" + Program.LibraryCounter.ToString();
                            RecursiveCopy(SourceDir, PathToSwitch);
                        }
                        string temppath = Path.Combine(DestDir, subDir.Name);
                        RecursiveCopy(subDir.FullName, temppath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo CurrentDir = new DirectoryInfo(DestDir);
                        RecursiveCopy(SourceDir, (Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + "Library" + Program.LibraryCounter.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (PathTooLongException)
            {
                DirectoryInfo DirInst = new DirectoryInfo(SourceDir);
                OutOfReachAreas.Add(DirInst.FullName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError During Copying:\n" + e.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++Program.LibraryCounter;
            FirstTime = false;
            ToSwith = true;
            string LibraryToMake = Program.DestinationContainer + "\\" + "Library" + (Program.LibraryCounter.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Building Library" + (Program.LibraryCounter.ToString()) + "...");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(LibraryToMake);
            RecursiveCopy(SourceDir, LibraryToMake);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Your method has to be recursive in order to copy all the subfolders in the hierarchy.

Comment: You might want to check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389701/how-to-create-a-recursive-function-to-copy-all-files-and-folders

Comment: The two NET USE calls are concurrent. Probably not what you want.

Comment: I added an update showing the stuff I've been working with based on the MS article mentioned in the question @chais posted in his comment.

Comment: Would it possibly work to create a list containing lists that contain filepath strings(List<List> ListSum = new List<List>();(Containing) List<string> Filepaths(numbered) = "Paths of folders and files"; being created by the method then passed to another method that works through those lists with foreach(var list in ListSum)then foreach item in those do work. Would that work? Does that make sense?

Comment: Just put up new info on how it's going and the code I have that looks like it's working so far. More details above.

Comment: The Code I just put up works until I hit the PathToLongException catch statement. It works for the first item passed through the catch(create a mapped X: drive to the long path and passing that through but when it hits the foreach it's mapping the X: drive for each item so it loses connection to the array being Enumerated(var file in "files") I think I may need to use a library that can utilize long paths. I will need to do some research on that.

Comment: It's weird it works great up till around the 15th library it creates then it keeps copying the same material. Up till that point it's working great but then it just keeps copying a specific folder. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Like chais said in comments, you need the subdirectory search to be recursive.

The MS example calls itself for EACH subdirectory, so it walks the entire directory tree. You could do something similar by replacing:

```
    foreach (var dir in FolderList1)
    {
        Destination = Destination + "\\" + dir.Name;
        CopyItems(dir, Destination);
    }
```

with

```
    foreach (var dir in FolderList1)
    {
        Destination = Destination + "\\" + dir.Name;
        CopyItems(dir, Destination);
        foreach (Directory subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            BreakMain(subDir, Destination);
        }
    }
```

You've got some other things that will have to be fixed to move to this recursive design, but that's the jist of the MS example.

Comment: I'm working out the other problems I have in the code but please take a look at the question in the (Edit: ) section, while this gives me the ability to recursively copy files and folders under ideal conditions it doesn't account for breaking up the source directory or the System.IO.PathToLongException on the good 50% of the source that will throw that exception. Also in the MS example they had a foreach within the method itself to call the method for the subDirs, when the method is called will that foreach not be reset?(Honest question.)

Comment: The work will be to combine your 4500 record split and PathToLongException into the recursive call. The foreach will not be reset, it will be on the stack. This automatically nests the foreach loops until you run out of subdirectories, then walks back out of them. You will need to make sure you don't use class-level variables, but move those variables into the method. From your two code snippets, you have the choice of starting with the MS example and adding the 4500 and path handlers, or starting with your code and making it recursively call itself for each directory it finds.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that when I was looking at it running, I believe I found a solution that seems to be working. I'm putting up the new code now.

Comment: The Code I just put up works until I hit the PathToLongException catch statement. It works for the first item passed through the catch(create a mapped X: drive to the long path and passing that through but when it hits the foreach it's mapping the X: drive for each item so it loses connection to the array being Enumerated(var file in "files") I think I may need to use a library that can utilize long paths. I will need to do some research on that.