# C# winforms program: need to copy files onto another windows PC

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a c# winform program that can copy some files onto another windows PC. Both PCs are running Windows 7 but the destination doesn't have folders shared.
I've no problems running scp to copy files onto a Linux box, but there's no SSH server waiting for me in Windows :-( 
I'll have the login details for the remote PC (IP address, username and password) but I'm unfamiliar with how this would normally done in a Windows environment.
Aim of this program is to automate deploying some update files to multiple machines. We won't be able to use windows shares to transfer these files as this is no quicker than manually logging in and copying the files via vnc.

Comment: It seems like you need to define how to copy files to the remote machine before you can write an application which would automate that.  That may be more of a question for SuperUser.

Comment: How would you go about copying the file(s) onto the remote machine?

Comment: By exposing a file share, or an FTP server, or some other kind of service which is designed for file transfers.

Comment: You can't copy a file to a remote machine if there is nowhere to put it. Why don't you just create  share on the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research on the Internet and experimented against a Windows XP machine (it's the only machine I happened to have with a local admin account on it - hopefully it will work OK against a Windows 7 machine).

Eventually I realised that a remote share was the right way forward - thanks to those who posted comments:-)

Please note in the example code I used a class instance called mDisplay - it was for handling display things for me such as showing an error message or results, not central to the problem at hand.

First problem - how to create a share on a remote machine without manual intervention.

```
public bool CreateShare(string ipAddress, string username, string password, string remoteFolder, string sharename)
{
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        // Create management scope and connect to the remote machine
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Username = username;
        options.Password = password;
        string path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", ipAddress);
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
        scope.Connect();

        // http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/creating-a-remote-share-using-wmi-in-c-sharp
        ManagementPath winSharePath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Share");
        ManagementClass winShareClass = new ManagementClass(scope, winSharePath, null);
        ManagementBaseObject shareParams = winShareClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        shareParams["Path"] = remoteFolder;
        shareParams["Name"] = sharename;
        shareParams["Type"] = 0;
        shareParams["Description"] = "Temporary folder share";
        ManagementBaseObject winShareResult = winShareClass.InvokeMethod("Create", shareParams, null);

        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        mDisplay.showError("FAILED to create share: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Second problem - copying over files from local machine to remote machine

Thanks to [How to create a recursive function to copy all files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389701/how-to-create-a-recursive-function-to-copy-all-files-and-folders) for basis of this code.
My version isn't necessarily the most efficient or compact way of doing the job, but it worked for me.

```
public bool CopyFiles(bool overwrite, string ipAddress, string sharename, string copySource)
{
    bool result = false;

    string path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", ipAddress, sharename);

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        mDisplay.appendToResults("Share doesn't exist \"" + path + "\" - are you sure it mapped ok?");
        return result;
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(copySource))
    {
        mDisplay.appendToResults("Source folder \"" + copySource + "\" doesn't exist, need to specify where to copy file(s) from");
        return result;
    }

    recursivelyCopyContents(copySource, overwrite, path);
    result = true;

    return result;
}
private void recursivelyCopyContents(string sourceDirName, bool overwrite, string destDirName)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            mDisplay.appendToResults("Creating folder " + destDirName);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

            string info = "Copying " + file.Name + " -> " + temppath;


            if (!overwrite && File.Exists(temppath))
            {
                // Not overwriting - so show it already exists
                mDisplay.appendToResults(info + " (already exists)");
            }
            else
            {
                file.CopyTo(temppath, overwrite);
                mDisplay.appendToResults(info + " OK");
            }
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            recursivelyCopyContents(subdir.FullName, overwrite, temppath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        mDisplay.showError("Problem encountered during copy : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Finally - Removing the remote share I created earlier, don't want it left on the remote machine.

```
public bool RemoveShare(string username, string password, string ipAddress, string sharename)
{
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        // Create management scope and connect to the remote machine
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Username = username;
        options.Password = password;
        string path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", ipAddress);
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
        scope.Connect();

        // Inspiration from here: https://danv74.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/list-network-shares-in-c-using-wmi/
        var query = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("select * from win32_share where Name=\"{0}\"", sharename));
        var finder = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        var shares = finder.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject share in shares)
        {
            share.Delete();
        }

        mDisplay.appendToResults("Share deleted");
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        mDisplay.showError("FAILED to remove share: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```